# no puedo descargar pdf 504 gateway timeout

Tags: php, laravel, nginx

Intento descargar un pdf y mi tabla tiene 2900 registros;
me funciona muy bien en mi computadora, pero en la nube me muestra 504 gateway timeout.
si en mi controllador le pongo un paginate(10) no tiene problema alguno

**Mi controllador**

```
        $date = now();$date = $date->toDateString();

        $item = Item_warehouse::join('articles', 'item_warehouses.article_id', '=', 'articles.id')
            ->select([
                'articles.name',
                'articles.model',
                'articles.brand',
                'articles.purchase_price',
                'item_warehouses.article_id',
            ])
            ->selectRaw('SUM(item_warehouses.stock) as totalStock')
            ->selectRaw('SUM(item_warehouses.stock * purchase_price) as total')
            ->groupBy('item_warehouses.article_id')
            ->get();
        $total=0;
        foreach ($item as $a){
            $total += $a->total;
        }

        $pdf=PDF::loadview('report.articles.pricetotal',compact('item','date','total'));
        //return $pdf->stream();
        return $pdf->download('ReportePrecio.pdf');
```

mi vista solo he colocado la parte de la tabla el resto es mismo html

**Mi vista a descargar**

```
<table width="100%" style="position: relative;top:70px">@foreach ($productos as $a)
        <tbody style="border-bottom: black 1px outset">
        <tr>
            <th rowspan="3"><img src="{{storage_path("/app/public/articles/$a->image")}}"class="img-pdf"/></th>
            <th></th>
            <td colspan="7"><strong>{{$a->name}} {{$a->model}} {{$a->colour}} {{$a->size}}</strong></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="6">Codigo: {{$a->code}}</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="4">Unidad M.: {{$a->um}}</td>
            <th></th>
            <th></th>
            
        </tr>
        </tbody>@endforeach
</table>
```

esta es la configuracion que he hecho en mi php.in

**php.ini**

```
max_execution_time = 0
memory_limit  = 10000M
post_max_size = 16M
upload_max_filesize = 8M
max_file_uploads = 20
max_input_time   = 60
```

Comment: prueba con  `set_time_limit(0);` al inicio del script

Answer (score 0):

cuando estas de manera local al hacer la consulta los datos te los devuelve practicamente al instante por lo que no tienes problema de tiempo de espera agotado, pero cuando estas en la nube o en un servidor los tiempos de la consulta tienden a ser mayores
intenta utilizar

`set_time_limit(0);`
o verifica en la configuración de tu servidor

para quitar el limite de tiempo directamente en tu script.

si el tiempo que tarda en descargarte el pdf sigue siendo mucho tienes que optimizar la consulta que estas realizando